# Multiuser wiki that I can edit/archive in Emacs Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, emacs-wiki

If I could live entirely in Emacs, I would. But... I now have to collaborate with others on a shared wiki and my team requires a web interface to edit pages.

So I need to select a wiki engine. Ideally, while my team can update pages though the web, I would be able to do the same, entirely from within Emacs. The features I am looking for broadly include:

1. Open source and self-hosted
2. Git based wiki that I can checkout and archive locally, pulling changes and pushing updates as I go. Bonus points if it works with `Magit`
3. Access and edit via Emacs org-mode. If the entire wiki could live on my computer as a single `org-mode` document, that would be fantastic!
4. Easily install the wiki engine locally on my mac for config/testing and then easily porting this to the production server for deployment
5. Bootstrap themes available
6. Supported with a healthy developer community
7. Flat file architecture. I don't want to mess with databases

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know exactly what features do you want but, in my work we use hugo, it support org mode, and it is easily managed with Magit, it also have really nice themes similar to wikis like https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-theme-techdoc/
Ans it is easy to use, just with gitlab pages or github.

Comment: Thanks @f-sasa. I love this! And ideally, I would love to use `ox-hugo` to manage my entire wiki from within a single `org` document, with git to push/pull changes. But... I thought Hugo was a blogging engine? Can this be made to work as a wiki?

Comment: It can, the thing is, the entire team have to know how to use git, but if it is the case, it shouldn't be any problem.
With gitlab/github private pages, it can be a powerful wiki and the code would look fantastic out of the box.
We use gitlab pages and it is great https://about.gitlab.com/stages-devops-lifecycle/pages/

Comment: So depending on the project, my team may have varying degrees of technical acumen. I live in Emacs and would like to do everything I can in `org-mode`, including manage documentation for our company's operating manual. However... I also need this document to be accessible to my team with a web interface, so that they can contribute. Ideally, I would find a git-backed wiki that also has an html editor. Ideally, I would find something with the ease of installation, portability and plugin repository of Dokuwiki but git-backed with native support for `org-mode` (like Gollum?).

Comment: Maybe you can use dokuwiki, there is an interesting mode to publish content with it, and you can always use xwidget browser or eww if you need to use the interface 
https://github.com/w-vi/ox-wk.el
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9794/org-mode-to-dokuwiki-converter
If you still need more functionality, you can always use the dokuwiki api and create an emacs package.

Comment: @f-sasa Thanks, I think that will do it! And it looks like I might be able to combine `ob-wk` with either `org-babel-detangle` or `org-tangle-sync` so changes can get round-tripped back into `org-mode`. Awesome! Hey, you you want to write this up, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Sure,thank you!

Comment: I thought you were going to accept @f-sasa 's answer: what happened? Does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use dokuwiki, there is an interesting mode to publish content with it, and you can always use xwidget browser or eww if you need to use the interface, [oxk.el](https://github.com/w-vi/ox-wk.el) is a great package for exporting org mode to wiki format. If you still need more functionality, you can always use the dokuwiki api and create an Emacs package.